# Programmatically detect COM port Arduino is connected to with php

Tags: php, batch-file, arduino

In my case my Arduino Uno is connected to COM6. With the next batch script I get that string

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption  /format:list ^| find "Arduino Uno"') do (
    call :setCOM "%%~J"
)

:: end main batch
goto :EOF

:setCOM <WMIC_output_line>
:: sets _COM#=line
setlocal
set "str=%~1"
set "num=%str:*(COM=%"
set "num=%num:)=%"
set port=COM%num%
echo %port%
```

The problem I have now is to use that information in my php program

```
<?php
 /**
 *Remember to go to Device Manager> Ports (COM & LPT)>Arduino XXX (COMXX)>right click>Properties>
 *Port Settings>Advanced>uncheck "use FIFO buffers ........."
 * In other hand, remember that the Tx speed has to be the same in PhpConnect.php, in Arduino sketch and in the COM
 * properties in Device manager, I selected 115200 b/s.
 * 
 */
 $output = exec("mode COM6: BAUD=115200 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 XON=off TO=on dtr=off odsr=off octs=off rts=on idsr=off");
$fp = fopen("COM6", "r+");
//sleep(2);
if (!$fp)
{
   exit("Unable to establish a connection");
}
// RX form PC**************
$t = $_POST['text1'];
// TX to Arduino****************
$writtenBytes = fputs($fp, $t);
//sleep(1); //cuando quite el sleep de aqui, se arreglo la demora de 1 minuto
// RX from Arduino**************
$j=0;
$dataset1 = [];
while(!$buffer=stream_get_line($fp,400,">")) { 1; }
// TX to PC***************
$piecesa = explode(",", $buffer);
foreach ($piecesa as $value) {      
            $dataset1[$j] = $value;
            $j++;       
}
//$dataout = array($dataset1);
$myJSON = json_encode($dataset1);
echo $myJSON;
ob_flush();
flush();
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This port changes from pc to pc thats why, I need to replace that information in every pc I connect my device.

I have googled but nothing, all variants I have proved do not give me the solution. Of course, may be I am making a mistake somewhere, please help me.

Comment: Why not just run the batch file from your PHP script? Or run the commands in the batch file from your PHP script?

Comment: I'd be interested to see the output from `"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe" Path Win32_PnPEntity Where "Caption Like '%Arduino%'" Get /Value`, run directly in the Command Prompt. _Because there just has to be a better way of getting the COM port._

Comment: Simply create a .bat file, connect your arduino to your pc via USB and run your batch file in the cmd and you are going to receive, for example, COM3, check Device Manager to confirm.

Comment: miken32 I have tried many variants from Google and I have gotten nothing.Have you an example of php that run a .bat and show the output data of the .bat file?